# List apps on SD card

Tags: lineageos, adoptable-storage

I'm running LineageOS 14 (Android 7) and my SD card was formatted as adoptable storage. I want to revert it to portable storage, without loosing apps, so I need to move those apps back to internal storage beforehand.

However I don't know which apps are stored on the SD card just now, and checking them manually, one after the other, using the Settings menu, is quite slow and error-prone.

How do I get a list of apps that are stored the SD card?

Comment: A drastic measure could be to remove the SD card, and note all the apps that will not work properly

Answer (score 0):

<del>Very simple use the file manager and browse to `sdcard/Android/data` all the apps are there. Using solid explorer I can even see the app icons.</del> (Not guaranteed, can show apps that don't store data on the SD card)

Alternatively you can just view the storage settings, click the sdcard f2fs and then apps and they are all listed there.

Comment: Note that `sdcard/Android/data` only lists data apps stored on the card. By what's there you cannot tell whether an app having its data here is installed on SD card or internal. I have several data directories in that place though I haven't installed a single app on SD card.

Comment: Huh, TIL thanks @Izzy. The second method it is then.

Comment: There is a hidden directory on the card containing moved apps. But without root, you cannot see it. I don't remember the name (as I never used that myself), something like `.android_secure` (and files with the extension `.asec`) I vaguely remember.

Comment: I agree with Izzy the first solution (`sdcard/Android/data`) is not 100% correct. The second one seems to have the same problem, because it lists apps that _take_ _space_ from the sd card, which are not necessarily the same that are _installed_ there. Though both solutions might just be _good_ _enough_, depending on the list size and other factors, they aren't in my case.